# Usb removed too early - GUI not loading

Tags: usb, 13.10, windows, gui

I'm running a dual boot(13.10 and Windows 8) ... and after removing an USB stick too early(in Ubuntu), the GUI isn't loading at startup on both OSs ... I can only access the Ubuntu GUI by starting the tty, logging in as root and then using startx. Is there a way of restoring the GUIs ?

Comment: When exactly did you remove the USB? Removing the USB without proper removal isn't an issue as long as the USB wasn't writing anything.

Comment: I was transferring an mp4 video to my USB.